# Validating excel data when mapping to DTO

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, validation, automapper

I am importing excel files to database using OpenXML library, so I map DataRow
to my custom object and later get it into database.
I want to validate each column in excel during mapping process and throw some user friendly exception that will be later show in UI.
For Example you are missing SYSTEM_ID Column,
or SYSTEM_ID is not in correct format.
For Example if I leave empty SYSTEM_ID or delete that column I will get automapper exception that is not user friendly.

This is how I map now:

```
CreateMap<DataRow, ESM_COMP_USERS>()
            .ForMember(a => a.COMP_USER_ID, a => a.MapFrom(b => int.Parse(b["SYSTEM_ID"].ToString())))
```

Can it be done with some customResolver ? And what would be the most scalable solution since I need to do mapping from string to int,bool,decimal.